# Google Places review - owner or business name?

Tags: website-review, google-places

I currently manage a Google Places Business, where we have received several reviews. I am wanting to respond to these reviews but I want to respond as the company, not as myself. I am the 'owner' of the page, it is through my personal Gmail address.

Like Facebook, when replying to comments and posts by other users on the business' wall, you reply as the actual business, not as your personal name.

Is this the case with Google Places? If not, how can I get it so the reviews are posted as the company name, not my personal name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst logged in to Google+, click on your profile image in the top left corner and in the dropdown should be the pages that you are an owner / manager of. Selecting one of these will allow you to then use Google+ as your page. You should know when you are using the network as a page as the profile name and your profile image will change to that of your page.